# Call a React Component inside another component's function

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying React right now and i stumbled upon a idea. I wish to call a react component from the function of another react component. however, i cant get it to work. Below is my code,

```
var Snaker = React.createClass({
componentDidMount: function() {
    $('.snacker').fadeIn(500);
    $('.snacker').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
  },
    render: function() {
    return <div>
              <div className="snacker snacker-right-top">
                <p>{this.props.message}</p>
              </div>
           </div>
    }
});

var Handle = React.createClass({
        showSnaker: function(){
        <Snaker message="React React"/>
    },
        render: function() {
      return <div>
                            <Snaker message="React's example"/>
                <a href="#" onClick={this.showSnaker}>Show me</a>
             </div>
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Handle />,
    document.getElementById('container')
  );
```

In the Handle component, i called the `Snaker` component and it works fine. However, what i want is the call the `Sanker` component when the link is clicked.I feel that this should do, however I cant get it to work. The JSFiddle to the same is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/55685/). Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: your `showSnaker` function is doing nothing right now..

Comment: @Hardy, the showSnaker is called on link click. I checked by adding an alert to it and it is being called successfully. However, the calling the Snaker inside it does nothing.

Comment: yes i know it does nothing.. why would it?

Comment: @Hardy, i don't think i'm getting you. Can you please explain a little?

Comment: that function just includes line `<Snaker message="React React"/>` so it doesn't do anything.. JSX should always be rendered somewhere.. so you could for example return that JSX and use it inside the render function.

Comment: @Hardy, Yes, i got that idea as well . Somewhere along the way i figured it has no place where it can be rendered. I am currently working on that only. Also, the answer by David is something that could be used. However, i'm afraid i won't be using the same thing but it got me started. Actually i have a set of errors that i need to display to the user and thus i need to loop over those errors and call the Error components that i have. (here it is Snaker). I'll be posting a new question soon if i get stuck. Hope to see you there as well :)

Comment: @Hardy, hey, if its not too much can you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39530695/setstate-inside-a-loop-react please? Also, your suggestion worked for me and i did what i wanted at the end of the day. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/55689/

```
var Snaker = React.createClass({
componentDidMount: function() {
    $('.snacker').fadeIn(500);
    $('.snacker').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
  },
    render: function() {
    return <div>
              <div className="snacker snacker-right-top">
                <p>{this.props.message}</p>
              </div>
           </div>
    }
});

var Handle = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
    return {clicked: false};
  },

    showSnaker: function(){
        this.setState({clicked: true});
    },

        render: function() {
      return <div>
                {this.state.clicked ? <Snaker message="I am Rahul Gavande"/> : ""}
                <a href="#" onClick={this.showSnaker}>Show me</a>
             </div>
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Handle />,
    document.getElementById('container')
  );
```

for why it works, you are triggering the function showSnaker which in turn sets the clicked state to true. In react whenever a state changes it triggers a render and I have set the ternary operator check if the clicked state is true, to make the Snaker component visible and if not set, to show nothing `{this.state.clicked ? <Snaker message="I am Rahul Gavande"/> : ""}`

Comment: This does the trick. I'll have to modify the code for it to work according to what exactly i want. Will definitely get back to you for same. Thanx a ton.

Comment: @Aakanksha no problem, just remember how react works, whenever there is a state change, react automatically triggers a re-render, check the react docs for more info