# setState inside a loop - React

Tags: ajax, reactjs, state, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to build a questionnaire in react. For now, all my answers will be accepted using the textbox. These will then be sent to my api using the ajax call. I want my params to have following structure,

```
questionnaire: {
                {question: "question", answer: "answer"},
                {question: "question2", answer: "answer2"},
                {question: "question3", answer: "answer3"}
               }
```

My code so far is really messy but somehow i'm getting the desired results. However, i'm unable to update the state of my answer and keep getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SubmitButton from '../components/SubmitButton'

export default class QuestionaireContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = { q: this.props.data,
                   questionaire: [],
                 };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var q = this.state.q
    var questionaire = this.state.questionaire
    q.map(function(map){
      questionaire.push({"id": map.id,
                         "question": map.question,
                         "answer": '',
                        });
    })
    this.setState({questionaire: questionaire})
  }

  submit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
      questionaires: this.state.questionaire
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/questionaries/save_questions",
      data: data,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: ()=>{
        alert("hello")
      }
    })
  }


  render() {
    var questionNodes = this.state.questionaire.map(function(question){

      var updateTextBox = (e) => {
      console.log(question.answer);
      this.setState({"answer": e.target.value});
      }

      return (
        <li key={question.id}>
          <div className="box-sed">
            <div className="que-set registration question-type">
              <span className="icon-ahead">
                <i aria-hidden="true" className="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
              </span>
              <h2>{question.question}</h2>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500's, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
            <div className="registration question-type">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Type answer" className="input-text" value={question.answer} onChange={updateTextBox} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="question">
        <form onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}>
          <ul>
          {questionNodes}
          </ul>
          <SubmitButton/>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, the params are a array and not a hash now.I cant figure out how else to set the initial state with my questions. The code might be really dirty but i'have only been able to do this yet.

I might not be making myself very clear so kindly bear with me and drop a comment so i could help you to better understand what i want. Any changes and suggestions will be great. Thanks in advance :)

**--UPDATE--**

I ended up taking Daniel's advice and put the text box in another react components and called it in the parent one.

Also, i *omitted the whole state thing inside loop and moved forward with the `this.props`*. I updated the `text box's` state in the child component (`QuestionaireComponent`) and used its state in the parent `QuestionaireContainer` component using the `refs`.

Following is my final code that got me working:

**QuestionaireContainer.jsx**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SubmitButton from '../components/SubmitButton'
import QuestionaireComponent from '../components/QuestionaireComponent'

export default class QuestionaireContainer extends React.Component {

  submit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
      questionaires: []
    }
    this.props.data.map(map => {
      data.questionaires.push(this.refs[map.id].state)
    });
    console.log(data);
    console.log("Done");
  }
  render() {
    var questionNodes = this.props.data.map(questions => {
      return (
        <QuestionaireComponent question={questions.question} key={questions.id} id = {questions.id} ref={questions.id}/>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="question">
        <form onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}>
          <ul>
          {questionNodes}
          </ul>
          <SubmitButton/>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and **QuestionaireComponent.jsx**

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react'    
export default class QuestionaireComponent extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    question: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { answer: '',
                   question: this.props.question,
                   id: this.props.id,
                 };
  }
  updateTextBox = (e) => {
    this.setState({answer: e.target.value})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <div className="box-sed">
          <div className="que-set registration question-type">
            <span className="icon-ahead">
              <i aria-hidden="true" className="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
            </span>
            <h2>{this.state.question}</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500's, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
          </div>
          <div className="registration question-type">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Type answer" className="input-text" value={this.state.answer} onChange={this.updateTextBox} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone whose looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
var questionNodes = this.state.questionaire.map(function(question){
```

Into

```
var questionNodes = this.state.questionaire.map(question => {
```

Because in your code function(question) override the context variable `this`.

Comment: I replaced the `function(question)` with `=>` and the error for `this.setState` is gone. However, this doesn't change my `state`. Do i have to update  `this.setState({"answer": e.target.value});` to something else as well?

Comment: It's better if you create another Component for each question.

Comment: How would i maintain the state then? i mean i did it initially but i started getting the uncontrolled components warning by React and the state did not get updated in the parent components ,i.e. QuestionaireContainer.

Comment: You should set an event onChange and update the state in QuestionairContainer

Comment: Do you think that my way of initailizing the state is right? with the loop and everyting? I highly doubt if this is the right way. Can you help me with an alternative?

Comment: I would do the same thing.

Comment: okay thanx. that boosts my confidence ;) I'll try with moving the textbox in a component again and let you know once i'm done.